# Capacitor as filter, physics behind choice

Tags: noise, decoupling-capacitor, frequency-response

I am tapping into the output voltages (signal wire) of various sensors on a vehicle, and I would like to use decoupling capacitors to filter out noise.

As others have stated, a rule of thumb is to use a 0.1uf and 10uf capacitors.

My question is related to how the 2 capacitors work together. Based on what I put together, the capacitors have a very high impedance at certain frequencies (or ranges) and therefore block them. I found a 10uf cap and a 0.33uf cap datasheets  with plots of frequency vs impedance (had difficulty finding a 0.1uf plot.)

I think the best way to phrase my question is this;

**What happens if I use the following 2 capacitors in parallel (10uf and 0.33uf) for noise filtering a DC analog signal with an approximate noise frequency of:**

1. 10Hz
2. 0.001MHz
3. 0.8MHz (corresponds to min impedance of 0.33uf cap)
4. 6MHz (corresponds to min impedance of 10uf cap)
   5) 100MHz

[image]

EDIT: Bad question, i need a low pass filter and not decoupling capacitors. At-least now i know about Anti-Resonance in case i need it in the future.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. The term you are looking for is "anti-resonance"

Comment: Use Murata Simsurfer to find impedance plots of MLCCs. Package matters. And don't discount parallel caps of the same value or ferrite beads at higher  frequencies where caps no longer work.

Comment: Decoupling is not the same as filtering.  The rule of thumb (use 10uF in parallel with 0.1uF) applies to decoupling.  Decoupling is used on the **power supply** to the circuit or on the supply lines to components.  Filters are applied to the signal.  Which do you need to do:  Clean up the power to the sensor, or clean up the signal from the signal?

Comment: Don't forget about piezo effects of ceramic caps either or DC bias effects.

Comment: modifying the signal that is emitted by a vehicle sensor can have unforeseen and potentially catastrophic consequences

Comment: WOW, everyone is missing the big picture.  My first concern is the source of these sensors; are any of these from the power train or chassis?  Do you know what the output impedance of these sensors?  A 10uF can short out your signal and possibly cause a system malfunction. I do not recommend tapping into power train or chassis sensors.  But if you must tap then use a differential amplifier circuit to avoid loading these sensors or introducing noise.

Comment: the inductance, of the PCB and wiring and capacitor leads and capacitor PCB solder pads ------- all matter

Comment: @DKNguyen , you are correct. the term i needed to lookup was Anti-resonance. but this is wrong because i need a low pass filter not decoupling.also, no idea what piezo effect is for capacitor,its on the list now (i'm mechanical not electrical)

Comment: @JRE i need to clean up the signal, i believe a low pass filter is what i need to do after i figure out the noise frequency(s).

Comment: @RobB. . , i am 100% aware of how i can affect the vehicle by tapping into those sensors. I am using a Voltage follower Op-amp, measured resistance at input pin is ~5m ohm. i have tested the obd2 readings for the sensor, there is no difference in the values after tapping into them. and yes i have to tap into those sensors for my project.

Comment: @haxxor anti-resonance is always there if you mix caps for filtering or decoupling. I don't know why you would mix caps for filtering but if you do then you need to be aware of that. For filtering, your caps are in the signal path and so can obviously affect the signal. Most ceramic caps dieelectrics produce voltage (i.e. noise) under strain or vibration and vary capacitance quite a bit with temperature or DC bias which will affect your filter. So use C0G/NP0 if you possible.

Comment: @DKNguyen good to know, i was not planning on mixing caps for filtering, only for decoupling. i will use only 1 capacitor in a low pass filter for the signal noise.Thanks for pointing out  C0G/NP0 , i was going to use X7R because i didn't know any better. i will get  C0G/NP0 Caps for noise filtering.

Answer (score 0):

The Kemet KSIM tool supports simulating several values together to see antiresonance effects.

I wish Murata’s Simsurfer tool did that, but no.